# log4j2 problems when sending output to a file

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I have below log4j2.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_DIR">.</Property>
        <Property name="ARCHIVE">output.log</Property>
        <Property name="CONSOLE_PATTERN">[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</Property>
        <Property name="FILE_PATTERN">%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${CONSOLE_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="file" fileName="${LOG_DIR}/${ARCHIVE}" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${FILE_PATTERN}"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="com.my.example" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Then within main class I put:

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
```

and in the same class I log several messages using below lines:

```
    logger.trace("Starting application...");
    logger.info("This should be written to file, but doesn't");
```

When I am debugging my app:

- All my trace messages are written to console.
- Info messages (logger.info) are only written to console but not to
  the file. File is created but if I open it is empty. Why?

I have not tested when executing app (without debugging). I am wondering whether it is normal and only success on debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your Main class is in the com.my.example package or a sub package. So it is using that logger to log. That logger is only configured to go to the console. It has additivity set to false so it will not delegate to the root logger. Were it true then the root logger would log to the console a second time and then log to the file.

With your configuration the only way to log to the file is to log events from a logger other than one coming from the com.my.example package. For example, if you do

Logger logger2 = LogManager.getLogger("Test");
logger2.info("This will be written to the file");

it will actually go to the file.

Please see http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html where this is all discussed.